# How do Chinese people feel about the term 非中国人 to express non-Chinese people?

Tags: meaning, culture

I have found myself using the word 非中国人 to express what Chinese people would call 外国人 or 老外.

How do Chinese people feel about this word ?

Just to confirm I am using it with Chinese people.

Here are some examples of 非中国人 in place of 外国人 just to give you a feel for it in use.

住在北京的非中国人越来越多

会说中文的非中国人不是很少

你有非中国的朋友吗 ？

Comment: Could you put it in a sentence? Or add a context?

Comment: @dan Sure, every sentence that has the word 外国人 in it just put 非中国人 in it's place :) 非中国人对中国人有些刻板印象

Comment: Those sentences are bit odd but grammatical. The oddity leads to a bit racism or segregation. It seems that you deliberately make it odd to isolate Chinese from non-Chinese. But that's probably just me.

Comment: @dan I'm curious how Chinese people feel about it. Do you mind if I ask are you Chinese ?

Comment: "are you Chinese" is English, which sounds a question about English.

Comment: @dan 我不太明白你的意思。英文问题 ？我想知道中国人对那个词有什么感觉 ？如果你不是中国人那你的回答没有意义，我想知道你是不是中国人，如果你不想告诉我也行，我是随便问而已 :)

Comment: Oh，you asked me literally "are you Chinese".  Yes, I'm.  I thought you meant that how I take the question "are you Chinese" as a Chinese speaker.

Comment: @Kantura I think you need to detail a bit whether or not you say 非中國人 to Chinese/non-Chinese as a Chinese/non-Chinese. As many pointed out, telling 非中國人 to Chinese give an exclusion feeling and it's better to say 外國人.

Comment: I feel this term is neutral and has a technical feel to it. Actually I personally quite like this term, but perhaps that's because I'm a nerd. :)

Comment: @Betty Thanks Betty , btw are you Chinese ?

Comment: @Kantura Yes I am.

Comment: For a point of reference, consider how terms like "people of color" are usually preferred to "non-white people". Saying "non-white" is not only exclusionary but also implies that white is default and non-white deviates from that default.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, 非中国人 sounds more exclusive. **非** stresses '**are not**' (they are not Chinese)

外国人 sounds more neutral. **外国** indicates '**where** ones came from ( they are from outside of this country)'

- **非**我族类(其心也异) is not a friendly phrase
- **外**賓 is a welcoming term

To me, 非中国人 (non-Chinese) VS. 外国人 (foreigner) is like 非会员 (non-member) VS. 访客 (visitor/ guest)

老外 is an informal nickname for 外国人. Sounds casual and friendly.

Comment: +1 for giving the example of 非我族类. I'm a native mainlander, 非中国人 gives me a sense of a nationalist undertone as it emphasises the 'NOT' part. To me, '住在北京的非中国人越来越多' gives a similar vibe to a statement like 'There is an increasing non-local population in the neighbourhood'

Comment: Quote:- "In my opinion, 非中国人 sounds more exclusive", and also with a subtle undertone of "us and them"?

Comment: @Wayne Cheah Yes." 中国人,  非中国人"  does carry a subtle undertone of "us and them"

Answer (score 3):

As a Chinese, I feel that this person ( who make this term:非中国人） is not Chinese.

外宾： very friendly.

老外： friendly

外国人： (中性词) not good, not bad.

非中国人： No Chinese would say like this.

Comment: "洋人" is another way to call the foreigners, especially Western people. It's often not friendly, especially in "洋鬼子". It means the person who says it out think that foreigner is aggressor.

Comment: the term 洋人 mostly refers to the westerners

Comment: the term 洋人 is dead, it's spoken by people 100 years ago.

Comment: it is alive and well on TV. and movies

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of the term `非中国人` before. It sounds very unnatural.

It is syntactically and semantically correct, though. We just don't say that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, 非中国人 is the same as 外国人.

非 is a very formal word for negative without any motion behinds.

So if you want to rationally argue in some topics, it's safe to use both 非中国人 and 外国人.

---

On the opposite, 不 is much more oral, it can be very motional.

Like 不是中国人 can means both neutral and negative: "You are not qualified to be a Chinese (shame on you)". This is more complicate and you have to judge with the contents or tone.